# Worse performance after 1.9.2 update

Tags: upgrade, performance, ce-1.9.2.0, benchmark

On my local test system, 1.9.1 performed ok in the `ab` benchmark:

```
Requests per second:    2.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2065.882 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       413.176 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          60.29 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

After upgrading to 1.9.2, results are significantly worse:

```
Requests per second:    1.33 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3769.256 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       753.851 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          33.14 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

No errors are reported in the log. Is this normal? [1.9.2 update were supposed to improve the performance](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.html).

Or is performance benefit visible only when cache is enabled? (I have it disabled on a test system)

Comment: To be honest, your stats are a mile off anyway. You should be seeing around 30 requests/second per CPU core. Given yours are a magnitude out, a difference of 1 RPS isn't particularly telling of an issue.

Comment: your both results are too low because of `Time per request:       2065.882 [ms] (mean)` and `Transfer rate:          60.29 [Kbytes/sec] received` average magento install will show 10x times faster, i guess you have something else wrong, not only magento....

Comment: Turns out my local-desktop system had some period of degraded performance.

After uploading to shared hosting, enabling compilation and cache, I get:

`Requests per second:    4.97 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       603.456 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       201.152 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          121.99 [Kbytes/sec] received`

which is slightly better than drupal 6 on the same hosting.

I guess after enabling some full page cache module, it would be pretty acceptable.